# AWS S3 fails to store multiple objects (streaming them from MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, scala, amazon-s3, stream, gridfs

I have a problem with migrating all my objects from MongoDB to AWS S3. I have 66k objects in my Mongo collection and I want to migrate them to S3 since S3 is cheaper.

I am streaming files out from Mongo, get ObjectID and set it as a key for the object in S3.

Here is the code.

**FileController.scala**

```
def streamFiles = {
val enumerator = collection.find(BSONDocument()).cursor[BSONDocument].enumerate()

val processDocuments: Iteratee[BSONDocument, Unit] =
  Iteratee.foreach { document =>
    val documentJs = Json.toJson(document)
    val expiration = (documentJs \ "expiresOn").asOpt[DateTime]

    documentRepository.save(documentJs, expiration)
  }

enumerator.apply(processDocuments)
}
```

**DocumentRepository.scala**

```
def save(jsValue: JsValue, expiration: Option[DateTime]): Future[Try[String]] = {
val key = (jsValue \ "_id").as[BSONObjectID].stringify

cloudStorage.save(jsValue, key, expiration).map {_.map { value => key }}
}
```

**CloudRepository.scala**

```
def save(jsObject: JsValue, key: String, expiration: Option[DateTime]): Future[Try[JsValue]] = {
Future {
  Try {
    val s3ObjectStr = jsObject.toString()
    //persist object to S3
    save(s3ObjectStr, key, expiration)

    jsObject
  }
}
}

private def save(s3ObjectStr: String, key: String, expiration: Option[DateTime]): PutObjectResult = {
val bytes: Array[Byte] = s3ObjectStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
val stream: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)

val objectMetadata: ObjectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata()
objectMetadata.setContentType("application/json")
objectMetadata.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"" + key)
objectMetadata.setContentLength(bytes.length)
//set object expiration time
if(expiration.isDefined)
  objectMetadata.setExpirationTime(expiration.get.toDate)

val putObject: PutObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, stream, objectMetadata)
putObject.setStorageClass(StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy)
putObject.setMetadata(objectMetadata)

s3.putObject(putObject)
}
```

When I ran this on machine with 16 GB of RAM, after 10 min it reached the maximum memory. It migrate only 7k of my objects ... and 100 of them failed to save getting this errors from S3:

- peer not authenticated
- Socket Closed
- Broken pipe
- Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: RequestTimeout; Request ID: 7F11A6A792C7AE06)

Any ideas what happened or what to do?

Edit: Libraries and version

- "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"
- "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.9.0"
- scala: 2.11.6

Comment: What libraries are you using? Which versions?

Comment: I added the libraries as a edit in the post.

Comment: DocumentRepository.save returns a Future, but it appears to return the result of CloudRepository.save which is not a Future, and anyway the version of CloudRepository.save that you've shown is private. is there another public save method on CloudRepository which you're not showing?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I was using an intermediate method, forgot to add it. Now should be fine.

Comment: You are using a quite old and deprecated version of ReactiveMongo

Comment: I don't think the problems is mongo, the problem seems to be S3. Mongo streams all the objects but S3 fails to save them (bottle neck)